# Create a site to answer on campaign

Tags: force.com, force.com-sites, contact, campaign, campaign-member

I'm new at site on force.com so I don't have a full vision about it.

I created a site. My need is to display the campaign and then the contact can check the website and answer if he participates or not.

for that, I created two custom objects with master details refering to campaign and contact, because we can't access standard objects on site.

If the contact participates, the field Participate__c on the custom object will change to YES for instance.

Any idea how to do this please?